# "cannot open qos.h" when trying to use WinSock2

Tags: visual-studio, networking, sdk, winsock2, qos

The title sums it up. I installed the latest windows SDK [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). The console tries to access a folder named after an older SDK version (which I uninstalled) and a folder called "winsock2.h", which doesn't exist. The exact path of the header its trying to access is ***(x86)/windows kits/10.0.15063/um/winsock2.h***

. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you didn't update the search paths of your project after removing the old SDK and installing the new one.

Comment: Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: I have faced same error and changing SDK version fixed my problem. But I  have never changed or removed my old SDK. What would be optimal solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Very simple solution actually - went to Project -> my_project properties -> Configuration Properties -> General and changed "Windows SDK Version" to the latest one. Thanks @Remy Lebeau for pointing me in the right direction.